# pyspark - getting error 'list' object has no attribute 'write' when attempting to write to a delta table

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am attempting to read the first X number of rows of a delta table into a dataframe, and then write (overwrite) that back to the delta table. Here is code:

```
# read from entire delta table into dataframe
revEnrichRef = spark.read.format("delta").load("/mnt/tables/myTable")

# retrieve first 5 rows
dfSubset = revEnrichRef.head(5)
dfSubset.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/mnt/tables/myTable")
```

at this point I get the error: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'

I guess that means head returns list rather than a new dateframe. What I really want is a solution that will return x rows to a dataframe. Alternatively, have a way to do this without an intermediary dataframe is just as good. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so with the [limit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.limit.html) method. This returns a dataframe limited to the number of rows passed as the argument.

```
dfSubset = revEnrichRef.limit(5)
```

The [head](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.head.html) method is an action which will collect 5 rows from your dataframe as a list. (or a single Row object if n = 1)